# Eliminate the decimals in a datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a `DataFrame` with this format type `2018-08-13 00:03:50` but some of the data inside the data frame has this format type `2018-08-13 06:34:24.859000`.  How do I remove the `.859000` in the second format type so that everything stays as in the first format type?

I need all data in the `DataFrame` to be in the following format `2018-08-13 00:03:50`?

Comment: set the datetime column resolution to seconds

Comment: Isn't `DataFrame` part of pandas? If so, please use format `DataFrame` correctly and use the [tag:pandas] tag.

Comment: @pavi2410 I presume that doesn't round up, correct?

Answer (score 1):

First convert your time to Timestamp:

```
import pandas as pd
your_time = pd.to_datetime('2018-08-13 06:34:24.859000')

print(your_time)

#Timestamp('2018-08-13 06:34:24.859000')
```

Now, you can do:

```
your_time.replace(microsecond=0)

#output
Timestamp('2018-08-13 06:34:24')
```

---

For full dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time'] = ['2018-08-13 06:34:24.859000', '2018-08-13 06:45:24.859000']


#output

time
0   2018-08-13 06:34:24.859000
1   2018-08-13 06:45:24.859000

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond = 0))


#output
    time
0   2018-08-13 06:34:24
1   2018-08-13 06:45:24
```

A link to doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace

Comment: you don't need and `apply` to truncate a datetime; in this case just use `.dt.floor("s")`